# question about isotropic subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

if $V$ is a complex vector space of dimension $2n$ and $Q$ a bilinear form over $V$, the definition of an isotropic subspace is the following: $$\Lambda:Q(\Lambda,\Lambda) \equiv 0$$.
Suppose that $\Lambda$ is a moaximal isotropic subspae, i.e. it isn't contained in any isotropic supspace.
So i see that the dimension of any isotropic subspace is lower than $dim(V)/2$. Furthermore all maximal isotropic subspace must have the same dimension.
Are there some conditions such that all isotropic subspace must have dimension $n$? i think that in general this doesn't happen.

Comment: i think that if $Q$ is a quadratic form over an albegraic closed  field, than the dimension of a maximal isotropic subspace is equal to $n=dim(V)/2$

Comment: I presume your $Q$ is nondegenerate? If $Q$ is the zero bilinear form then the maximal isotropic subspace is the whole $V$.

Comment: yes non degenerate

Comment: @dario: To be precise, $n=\lfloor dim(v)/2\rfloor$ (assuming $Q$ is non-degenerate).